# Itirating through list of tuples with nested for loops

Tags: python, tuples

I have a list containing tuples. Each tuple holds 2 elements. I tried to print it with the following code, but it gives the error message:

`TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple`

Relevant code:

```
for i in list:
    for j in [1, 2]:
        print(list[i][j])
```

With the idea of printing each element of the 1st tuple, each element of the 2nd tuple etc

Comment: As @Miraj50 said, `i` is already a tuple. Just get rid of the nested loop and do `print(i[0], i[1])` on the first one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Realise `i` in the loop is actually a tuple (an element of a list). So, you just need to print element of `i` like `i[j]`. `list[i]` makes no sense as `i` should be an integer, but it is actually an element of the list, that is a tuple. You must also be getting an error like this `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple`. Well I am. So that should be a hint/explanation to you.

```
lst = [(1,2),(5,9)]
for i in lst:
    for j in [0, 1]:
        print(i[j])
    print
```

Output:

```
1 2
5 9
```

Comment: Try not to use the variable name `list` for assignment, either use `list_` or rename it completely. You shouldn't be assigning anything to stdlib names

Comment: op, nice timing :). Also remove the comma after `i[j]` and put parantheses around the `print`s and your code will be cross-compatible and working :)

Comment: you forgot the parantheses on the second print statement :)

Comment: @клйкбаутоьмажазвайкукас But there is one problem with that. In 2.x it will print an empty bracket!! Not good ! So I shall let the OP have what he wants!!

Comment: OP's code shows a moreover Python-3 inclined coding style, so I would either put `from __future__ import print_function` at the top or leave it as it is.

Answer (score 2):

You can unpack the tuple in the for loop

```
>>> tup_list = [(1,2), (3,4)]
>>> for a,b in tup_list:
...     print(a,b)
... 
1 2
3 4
```

Comment: the above answer dones't work, this answer works perfectly for me

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested list comprehension:

```
[i for subset in list for i in subset] give you flat list
```

It's more pythonic!